# How do I style a simple HTML table the same as the TreeGrid component?

Tags: angular, nebular

Sometimes I want just a static html table and it is an overhead to write all code needed to display a `TreeGrid` component. I wish I could write a simple plain HTML table (or at least, almost plain) that is styled the same as the `TreeGrid` component. I wrote the classes manually like in the code below, but that doesn't seem really good. Is there a way I can reuse TreeGrid styles in a simpler form?

```
<table class="nb-tree-grid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="nb-tree-grid-header-row">
            <th class="nb-tree-grid-header-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">Id</th>
            <th class="nb-tree-grid-header-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="nb-tree-grid-row">
            <td class="nb-tree-grid-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">1</td>
            <td class="nb-tree-grid-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nb-tree-grid-row">
            <td class="nb-tree-grid-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">2</td>
            <td class="nb-tree-grid-cell cdk-column-name nb-column-name">Julia</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit:

Example -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/nebular-tree-grid-styles

I just want to make sure that when Nebular updates their styles on TreeGrid, I'd get those updates on my plain HTML tables also. But writing all classes just feels a bit overwhelming. I was thinking about a custom directive that would inject these classes in a table as a cleaner solution.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I am also not good in Nebular, but I think you can do this thing using Nebular Tree Variables. Use the following way :

```
thead tr { background: var(--tree-grid-header-background-color);
  color: var(--tree-grid-header-text-color);
  font-family: var(--tree-grid-header-text-font-family);
  font-size: var(--tree-grid-header-text-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--tree-grid-header-text-font-weight);}
```

You can get more detail at [Nebular Tree](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/tree-grid/theme#nbtreegridcomponent)

Using Variables will make your custom HTML table as same as the Nebular tree table. You can get these variables by inspecting Nebular elements.